# ResourceBundle does not find entry in .properties file

Tags: java, spring, internationalization, resourcebundle

Using `org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` to retrieve messages from:

File name: *actionMessages.properties*
Locale: *en_US*
Base name: *actionMessages*

In this combination I expected to retrieve the messages from *actionMessages.properties*, what ever locale used, since there are no other base names configured, but all I get is a `NoSuchMessageException`.

Bean configuration:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
  <property name="basename" value="cfg/actionMessages" />
</bean>
```

Java code:

```
MessageSource messageSource = getMessageSource();
String message = messageSource.getMessage("code", null, new Locale("en", "US"));
```

Is there anyone who can tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Please show how you set up your message source and how you fetch the (not found) message.

Comment: @DirkLachowski I just added the snippets.

Comment: Looks ok. Looking at ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.refreshProperties() then either your properties file is not parsable or not found.

Comment: Even with the absolute path to the file it won't work; I have no idea what could be wrong. Probably the only way is to load the source code and debug it step for step.

Comment: Just a wild guess: The contents of the properties file is ok?

Comment: What is in getMessageSource() ?

Comment: getMessageSource() is just a getter returning the bean reference, nothing fancy there.

What could be possible wrong in a properties file? It is UTF-8 encoded (that's why I don't use the original MessageSource but this one, that supports UTF-8), the keys have only ASCII characters, the messages contain aswell German umlaute ÄÖÜ.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37746/discussion-between-dirk-lachowski-and-hannes)